# Angular - Smart-table - OR in filter

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, smart-table

I'm using the very good [Smart-table](https://github.com/lorenzofox3/Smart-Table) library to display my data. I have made a custom filter directive to allow me to assign filters to buttons, so that users can easily filter by row state (i.e. 'New', 'Done', 'Failed' etc). This works fine, but I'd like to be able to compound filters so that I could filter by rows containing one of two values in the state column (for instance 'New' and 'Failed').

My custom filter looks like....

```
app.directive('stCustomFilter', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '^stTable',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            var tableState = ctrl.tableState();
            var searchText = attr.stCustomFilter;
            var searchColumn = attr.stCustomFilterColumn;

            element.on('click', function(data) {
                tableState.search.predicateObject = {};
                ctrl.search(searchText, searchColumn);
                //console.log(tableState);
                scope.$apply();
            })
        }
    };
});
```

and is used as follows inside the st-table's thead.....

```
<div class="btn-group  btn-group-sm">
    <button st-custom-filter="" st-custom-filter-column="status">All</button>
    <button st-custom-filter="New" st-custom-filter-column="status">New</button>
    <button st-custom-filter="Done" st-custom-filter-column="status">Done</button>
    <button st-custom-filter="Failed" st-custom-filter-column="status">Failed</button>
</div>
```

So ideally, I'd like to be able to use something like "New||Failed" inside the st-custom-filter by altering the directive slightly, but I have a feeling that the answer may lie in writing something more complex involving the st-pipe method.

Can anyone offer a suggestion or two? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For a OR filter, which is not supported by the default angular filter filter, you'll have to set up a custom filter and tell smart-table to use this one in place of the default one

```
angular.filter('myCustomFilter',function(){
return function(array, predicteObject){
//the predicate object is forwarded by smart table whenever a directive call the search method.. for example :{ myProp1:'myInput1',myProp2:'myInput2
//process the array with your OR logic
}})
```

then tell smart table to use your custom filter in place of the default one

```
<table st-table="myCollection" st-set-filter="myCustomFilter"></table>
```

Comment: Hi Laurent, you response is much appreciated. I'll give this a go in the next day or two and come back with the relevant thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
scope.displayClients  = [].concat(scope.clients);
scope.predicates = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'];
scope.selectedPredicate = scope.predicates[0];

app.filter('myStrictFilter', function($filter){
 return function(input, predicate){
    return $filter('filter')(input, predicate, false);  //false -if contains     string, true if matches string
}})




scope.displayClients  = [].concat(scope.clients);
scope.predicates = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3'];
scope.selectedPredicate = scope.predicates[0];

app.filter('myStrictFilter', function($filter){
    return function(input, predicate){
        return $filter('filter')(input, predicate, false); // true for exact match 
}})
```